# TypeScript Error - Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0 or more. TS2556

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I was using this statement in JavaScript but when I try to use it in a TypeScript Project I get an error. It's complaining about the fetch(...args)

```
const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then(response => response.json());

Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0 or more.  TS2556
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `const fetcher = (args) =>` without the spread operator?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should help you:

```js
const fetcher = (...args: [input: RequestInfo, init?: RequestInit | undefined]) => fetch(...args).then(response => response.json());
```

You should explicitly type arguments for `fetch`. It expects 1-2 arguments.

If you want to use `rest` operator, you should tell TS, that you also expect two arguments in your higher order function

**UPDATE**

Generic approach. If you want to get type of arguments of any function, just use [Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) util.

```js
type FetchParameters = Parameters<typeof fetch>
```

Comment: Not sure why @jcatz deleted his response, as `const fetcher = (...args: Parameters<typeof fetch>) =>  fetch(...args).then(response => response.json());` is a nice solution, as it lines up the parameters types automatically for you using  Parameters & typeof.

Comment: @Keith, agree. Personally, I'm learning TypeScript by his answers ) They are (his answers) better than any docs | books I have read

Answer (score 3):

Taking this answer from comment by @Keith which was the only thing that worked for me:

```
const fetcher = (...args: Parameters<typeof fetch>) => {
  fetch(...args).then(response => response.json());
}
```

Specifically adding this `Parameters<typeof fetch>` as the type of `...args`