# Applying stolen fetch types to redefine urql Client fetch member doesn't satisfy Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, fetch-api, urql

I'm having a hard time trying to satisfy Typescript when redefining the fetch function on [@urql/core](https://github.com/urql-graphql/urql).

I found two SO answers that kind of nailed the problem, but somehow they doesn't work for me:

- [fetch answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65307025/typescript-error-expected-1-2-arguments-but-got-0-or-more-ts2556)
- [fetch answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74298685/a-spread-argument-must-either-have-a-tuple-type-or-be-passed-to-a-rest-parameter)

My code looks like this:

```
import { Client } from "@urql/core"

const client = new Client({
  fetch: async (...args: Parameters<typeof fetch>) => {
    const response = await fetch(...args);
// ...
```

And the Typescript complaint is:

> error| Type '(input: RequestInfo, init?: RequestInit | undefined) => Promise' is not assignable to type '{ (input: RequestInfo | URL, init?: RequestInit | undefined): Promise; (input: RequestInfo, init?: RequestInit | undefined): Promise<...>; }'. Types of parameters 'input' and 'input' are incompatible. Type 'RequestInfo | URL' is not assignable to type 'RequestInfo'. Type 'Request' is not assignable to type 'RequestInfo'. Property 'duplex' is missing in type 'Request' but required in type 'import("./node_modules/undici-types/fetch").Request'.

(path slightly edited to hide personal information)

I tried a simplified fetch replacement just to seek how to satisfy Typescript, and found that this code works fine:

```
const fetcher = async (...args: Parameters<typeof fetch>) => {
  const response = await fetch(...args)
  // ...
  return response
}
```

While this one gives me the **exact same error** as the initial snippet from above:

```
const originalFetch = global.fetch

global.fetch = async (...args: Parameters<typeof global.fetch>) => {
  const response = await originalFetch(...args)
  // ...
  return response
}
```

My main question is how to solve this issue and satisfy Typescript.

I tried different things before reaching for `Parameters<>` and every single attempt gave me a different Typescript error:

```
// The initial wasn't typed
global.fetch = async (...args) => {
  const response = await originalFetch(...args)
// No overload matches this call

// Secondly used the very same parameters shown on previous attempt error message
global.fetch = async (...args: [RequestInfo | URL, RequestInit | undefined]) => {
  const response = await originalFetch(...args)
// but then it complains about missing property 'referrer' from the `undici` type

// Thirdly I removed the `URL` option from the first parameter
global.fetch = async (...args: [RequestInfo, RequestInit | undefined]) => {
  const response = await originalFetch(...args)
// but it seems is needed cause "Type 'RequestInfo | URL' is not assignable to type 'RequestInfo'"
```

It's really puzzling seeing it working fine when I assign to whatever name, but breaking when trying to overwrite the global function. Since I'm trying to tamper with response data from `@urql/core`, I cannot use another method as I have to replace the `fetch` member from `Client`.